# aptitude is stuck in a loop after running apt autoremove

Tags: apt, grub2

I'm stuck on this menu any time I update packages:

```
  │ A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.  │
                            │                                                                                                                    │
                            │ What would you like to do about menu.lst?                                                                          │
                            │                                                                                                                    │
                            │                             install the package maintainer's version                                               │
                            │                             keep the local version currently installed                                             │
                            │                             show the differences between the versions                                              │
                            │                             show a side-by-side difference between the versions                                    │
                            │                             show a 3-way difference between available versions                                     │
                            │                             do a 3-way merge between available versions (experimental)                             │
                            │                             start a new shell to examine the situation                                             │
                            │                                                                                                                    │
                            │                                                                                                                    │
                            │                                                       <Ok>                                                         │
                            │
```

I tried to remove the kernel headers with apt autoremove to free up some space, and now any updates get stuck in this loop where no matter what you select it keeps showing you this menu.

Any idea how to correct the issue?

Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-170-generic x86_64)

```
dpkg -l | grep grub
ii  grub-common                      2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                    amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
ii  grub-efi-amd64                   2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                    amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-bin               2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                    amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 binaries)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-signed            1.66.17+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17            amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)
ii  grub-legacy-ec2                  17.2-35-gf576b2a2-0ubuntu1~16.04.2         all          Handles update-grub for ec2 instances
rc  grub-pc                          2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                    amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
ii  grub2-common                     2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                    amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
```

Comment: Use the <tab> key and select the option most appropriate for your use-case, ie. the package maintainers version is usually best, however if you've made local changes you may want to save your local version first (start new shell, or I usually switch to an alternate shell & `sudo cp` the conf file there), then later evaluate the change (what I usually opt to do).

Comment: @guiverc I've tried every options numerous times. It will run some process on apt and then end up on the same screen over and over again regardless of which options is chosen.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep grub` please.

Comment: @nobody ... Sure thing, added to original question as it was too long for a comment

Comment: Och, efi stuff. Please `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` I need to know bios or efi start.

Comment: It outputted -> `BIOS`. This is on Cloud hosting if it makes a difference. Digital Ocean specifically.